# Hide specific routes in react navigation drawer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, jsx, react-navigation-drawer

I am trying to use a route, but not make it visible so that it can just be clicked in the nav bar.

```
const StackDrawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const Draw = () => {
    return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <StackDrawer.Navigator>
                    <StackDrawer.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
                    <StackDrawer.Screen name="Copy" component={MainCopy} />
                </StackDrawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

The issue here is that it is now visible for anyone to click in the navigation bar.

How can I hide the "Copy" route from the nav bar but still use it?

Comment: You should just be able to use Stack Navigator to add routes without adding it to a UI. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/ Then in your components you can link to the routes in your stack navigator